# Hazelcast 3.5 client fails to reconnect after all server nodes went down

Tags: java, client, hazelcast, reconnect

I would like to ask you for a help. I have a problem with client reconnection to a HZ cluster in case whole cluster goes down and then gets up.

If HZ cluster keeps at least one node alive, there is no problem at all. But when all nodes goes down, related client never reconnect again.

Here's my client initialization code:

```
public void init() {

List<String> members = (List<String>)Arrays.asList("node1,node2,node3".split(","));
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.getGroupConfig().
             setName( "dev" ). 
             setPassword( "dev" );
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().
             setConnectionAttemptLimit( 10 ).
             setConnectionAttemptPeriod( 100 ).
             setConnectionAttemptPeriod( 1000 ).
             setRedoOperation(true).
             setSmartRouting(true).
             setAddresses(members);
hzClient = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
hzSessionMap = hzClient.getMap("mapsession");  
}

public IMap getSessionMap() {
    return hzSessionMap;
}
```

I have my client created as spring bean, which offers IMap objects.

Exception thrown when reconnect after whole cluster is restarted is:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: 
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
```

at 
    com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:380) ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:235) ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]
at
    com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:207) ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.toData(ClientProxy.java:169) ~[hazelcast-client-3.5.jar:3.5]
at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.put(ClientMapProxy.java:362) ~[hazelcast-client-3.5.jar:3.5]
    ...

Regards,

Josef

Comment: I found this in HZ 3.5 documentation: 
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/client/config/ClientNetworkConfig.html#setConnectionAttemptLimit(int)

setConnectionAttemptLimit
public ClientNetworkConfig setConnectionAttemptLimit(int connectionAttemptLimit)
While client is trying to connect initially to one of the members in the addressList, all might be not available. Instead of giving up, throwing Exception and stopping client, it will attempt to retry as much as connectionAttemptLimit times.

May it help if I set it to zero?

Comment: It helped the case, but if all HZ nodes are down, jboss server (and I bet any other server) could not be restarted gracefully and must be killed instead. Log is filled with HZ client notices about trying to connect ...

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  We are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: As I wrote above. Configuration is the key to success.

This configuration works for me:
    clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().
    setConnectionAttemptLimit( 300 ). // 5 min
    setConnectionAttemptPeriod( 100 ). // 100
    setConnectionTimeout( 1000 ). // 1000
    setRedoOperation(true).
    setSmartRouting(true).
    setAddresses(membersList); // address list

Comment: Only issue is, that during the time when hazelcast nodes are down, all instances of HZ client are trying to reconnect and jboss sometimes don't go down gracefuly. Shorter timeouts may help it.